# How to extract information from the NY Times Api?

Tags: r

I would like to extract information from the NY Times Api via `library(rtimes)`.
The api call returns a list of 3, which seems to contaion the informtion I require in a inaccessible way, for an R newbie.

```
install.packages("rtimes")
require(rtimes)
# Here I use the Key provides by the New York Times
api <- "[redacted]" 

# I create an empty vector to append required information to it,
mylist <- c()
 # The default article api call for "Crisis"
NY_terror<- as_search(q="Crisis",
                  begin_date = '20110101', 
                  end_date ='20110201',
                  fl=c("pub_date","headline","keywords","abstract","_id"),
                  facet_field=c("section_name"),
                  key = api)

  #Here I extract the data. At least I believe that
 mylist<- append(mylist, unlist(NY_terror$data))
```

But I just end with one required column "pub_date" as well as the freq. count of the corresponding keyword. May I ask how to produce a data frame with column defined in `fl`and `face_field`.

So the desired output should look something like:

```
 id  section_name         pub_date      headline  keywords  abstract

  ...      Politics       2011-01-01      MAMBA      ...     ...   
                                         posted
                                         API Key
```

Comment: you really don't want to go around sharing your API keys like this. even if you edit/delete the post it still exists in SO.

Comment: Yes, that was by mistake

Comment: @Mamba where is `dat` being created for the first time (you were using it in `append`)? I think you meant `mylist`? I edited it but please confirm this is what you meant: `append(mylist, unlist(NY_terror$data)) `

Comment: Aye. It happens. But you need to null that key and regen it. As I said, it's still viewable: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAFbaXIRTV5Jzols94fENqON-dsanYfQQ0wB/image.png

Comment: @hrbrmstr maybe he can wait until the question is answered so that it's still reproducible

Comment: Mebbe @Hack-R, but if an API key harvester found this already, Mamba cld get their account banned for abuse on NYTimes site.

Comment: @hrbrmstr o ok.  Hey Mamba can you get an example of what the desired result should look like?

Comment: @Hack-R, sorry, I meant  mylist() of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work to get you started and you can continue adding more fields in the same way:

```
b <- list()
for(i in 1:length(NY_terror$data$docs)){
  a <- as.data.frame(as.character(unlist(NY_terror$data$docs[[i]]$byline$person)))[5,1]
  b <- rbind(b,as.character(a))
 }
b <- unlist(b)
b # first author's last name (if given), can be expanded for multiple authors

c <- list()
for(i in 1:length(NY_terror$data$docs)){
  a <- as.data.frame(as.character(unlist(NY_terror$data$docs[[i]]$pub_date)))[[1]]
  c <- rbind(c,as.character(a))
}
c <- unlist(c)
c # dates

d <- list()
for(i in 1:length(NY_terror$data$docs)){
  a <- as.character(unlist(NY_terror$data$docs[[i]]$keywords[[1]]$value))
  d <- rbind(d,a)
}
d <- unlist(d)
d # keywords

res <- cbind(b,c,d)
res[,1] <- gsub("reported", "NA",res[,1])
res

      b           c                      d                                        
 [1,] "BOSMAN"    "2011-01-30T20:14:04Z" "Financial Crisis Inquiry Commission"    
 [2,] "CHAN"      "2011-01-29T09:00:03Z" "Regulation and Deregulation of Industry"
 [3,] NA          "2011-01-25T17:20:36Z" "Financial Crisis Inquiry Commission"    
 [4,] "CRAIG"     "2011-01-27T14:17:32Z" "Financial Crisis Inquiry Commission"    
 [5,] "MORGENSON" "2011-01-30T00:00:00Z" "Banking and Financial Institutions"     
 [6,] "BOSMAN"    "2011-01-31T00:00:00Z" "FINANCIAL CRISIS INQUIRY COMMISSION"    
 [7,] "CHAN"      "2011-01-25T00:00:00Z" "Subprime Mortgage Crisis"               
 [8,] "NA"        "2011-01-28T09:30:54Z" "Securities and Commodities Violations"  
 [9,] NA          "2011-01-25T02:15:29Z" "Justice Department"                     
[10,] "NOCERA"    "2011-01-29T00:00:00Z" "Banking and Financial Institutions"
```